# Safari can’t establish a secure connection to the server www.google.com

Tags: safari, gmail, error

If I try to navigate to any of the following pages:

- http://google.com/reader
- https://encrypted.google.com/

I get an error message in Safari saying:

> Safari can't open the page "https://encrypted.google.com/" because
>   Safari can’t establish a secure connection to the server
>   "encrypted.google.com"

I also find that on the Gmail page many images are missing and when I try to go the image location I see the same error as above. Here's a pic of the missing images:

[image]

In chrome I have the same issue but with a different error as follows:

> Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.

I am not using a proxy and this behaviour has started recently for seemingly no apparent reason although I did get a new router about 2 weeks ago. **Why am I experiencing  these problems?**

Comment: Couple things to check. 1. Did you visit China recently?
2. What version of Mac OS X?
3. DNS servers, what are they?
4. Version of Chrome? Version of Safari? My first thought is that there is some redirection going on when you visit those named domains, which could be related to DNS. second would be invalid certs.

Comment: I don't know if this is related to your issue or not, but there has been a *lot* of chatter in security circles about SSL/TLS issues lately (and not just Apple's problem.)  Many servers have been reconfigured to stop supporting a lot of older configurations known to be insecure, and I expect there to be issues where SSL/TLS just plain won't work for at least a little while.

Comment: Is this happening with any other HTTPS websites? Is your time and date correct? Is your copy of Chrome, Safari and OS X up to date?

Answer (score 1):

The issue with certificate trust is one that can break on the server side or the client side. Worse, [any intermediate certificate can fail or expire in a chain of trust](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428169/ios-marked-a-certificate-as-expired-even-though-the-certificate-is-still-activ) so it may not be the first certificate you inspect that causes the failure.

In the 2012 case, a temporary mismatch between what Google assumed was a trustworthy certificate chain and what apple has actually shipped caused this. When that gets sorted, you have an excellent chance of secure browsing from the main google entry page and all shipping versions of Safari.

- https://www.google.com

As each “root certificate” expires and as classes of certificates  and handshakes are deemed no longer secure, [this error will pop up again](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258184/safari-cant-open-the-page-because-safari-cant-establish-a-secure-connection) and either an OS update or server update is needed to fix it. As long as your macOS is getting security updates, you shouldn’t have to load new unexpired root certificates manually for sites as large as google.