# Safari can't open the page because Safari can't establish a secure connection

Tags: ios, safari

I am running Mac OS X 10.7.3 in VirtualBox. The reason is I have to deploy an old iOS app to the app store. And it runs on Xcode 4.3.2. If I try running the xcode on a newer version of Mac OS X, like 10.9.5, I would get an error “This installation of Xcode 4.3.2 requires Mac OS X 10.7 Lion.” My iPhone app is 100 percent complete and 100 percent working. I just need to deploy to app store. When I try to deploy on 10.7.3 on VirtualBox, I first try to go to Apple’s Developer Portal. I get the following message:

> Safari can’t open the page. Safari can’t open the page
>   “https://developer.apple.com/account/overview.action” because Safari
>   can’t establish a secure connection to the server
>   “developer.apple.com”.

I am looking for the quickest way to deploy this to the store. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

That's because developer.apple.com no longer supports older TLS and SSL protocols - it only supports TLS 1.2 (see https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=developer.apple.com). Older Safari versions (before version 7) do not support TLS 1.2  (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:TLS/SSL_support_history_of_web_browsers) .

You could try installing Firefox or another browser in the VM hoping they have updated certificate stores and will negotiate a secure connection for access to that site.